# How to get instagram access token according to latest instagram api rules?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I followed that official document - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started/

i get "code" using this link -

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code
```

i get code successfully.

i get access_token using commands

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \
  -F client_id={app-id} \
  -F client_secret={app-secret} \
  -F grant_type=authorization_code \
  -F redirect_uri={redirect-uri} \
  -F code={code}
```

Get results like this -

```
{
  "access_token": "IGQVJ...",
  "user_id": 17841405793187218
}
```

When i am using this access_token in my website then getting this error -

```
**Error from Instagram: The access_token provided is invalid.**
```

Comment: Got the same issue right now, saw this on a few other stack Qs but still no solutions. We must be missing some sort of scope permission somewhere I think?

Comment: I'm also desperately trying to get a solution for this problem and still can't find any way to do it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120138/unable-to-get-instagram-access-token-with-new-basic-instagram-api