# Unable to get Instagram access token with new basic Instagram API

Tags: access-token, instagram-api

I'm getting really frustrated with the new Instagram API, what I need to do is just get things like pictures, comments, and likes from my Instagram feed. I'm following all the steps that they mention over here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions, but I'm still not able to get the final access token I need in order to interact with the API. After getting a lot of different errors now I'm stuck with:

*{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"}*

I have verified everything in my Facebook developer setup and everything is ok, the OAuth URL is identical to the one I'm using in the curl command in order to return the access_token and all the setups seem fine. I have noticed that a lot of people are having the same problems but I can't find something that works for me.

This is the way I'm trying to retrieve the access_token:

```
curl -X POST https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token -F client_id=[client_id] -F client_secret=[code] -F grant_type=authorization_code -F redirect_uri=[url] -F code=AQDJxpW5h4r..
```

I have read that people are using postman and apparently it works over there but I don't know how to use it, any help will be really appreciated.

Upgrade on this, I was finally able to get the access_token via Postman and when I'm trying to use it now I got this error:

```
{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}
```

This is really disappointing, everything was working just fine before this API change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just review of the following in your checklist again:

1. APP_ID and APP_SECRET of "Instagram APP", which is a product added in the Facebook App.
2. Access Code once submitted in POST request using CURL or Postman, will become invalid for the next request.
3. The Website Platform is added in "Facebook App".
4. Test Instagram Users are added and are not pending.
5. Lastly, Authenticate using the Instagram Test User Profile.

Comment: turns out i was using facebook client secret instead of IG's, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and actually lost some time solving it.
In my case I only made the configuration in Instagram Product but didn't change the configuration in the login by facebook product.
In summary, you should have in your app in Facebook developers, two products, one Login by Facebook and the other one Instagram. Both must have the same redirect URL.
Hope this helps.

Comment: legend! this worked for me